# Upper bound on $\left\|u\right\|_{L^{\infty}([0,1])}$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I was wondering, does a function $u(x,t):[0,1]\times[0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ have to have a zero in $[0,1]$ for

$$\left\|u(\cdot,t)\right\|_{L^{\infty}([0,1])}\leq C\left\|u_x(\cdot,t)\right\|_{L^2([0,1])}$$

to hold? I know how to get it when $u(x,t)$ has at least one zero $x_0\in[0,1]$, but I am unsure on how, if possible, this would go if it does not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the right hand side does not change if we add a constant to $u$, but the right hand side does. So without any assumptions on $u$, e. g. $u$ having a zero, or having mean 0 (which implies $u$ has a zero, if $u$ is $H^1$), we cannot conclude. Looking at the constant $u_c(x,t) = c \in \mathbf R$ we have 
$\|u_c\|_{L^{\infty}} = c$, $\|u_x(\cdot, t)\|_{L^2} = 0$, so your inequality can only hold for $c = 0$.

Comment: Thanks! Deep down inside I was hoping I would be needing $u$ to have a zero anyway!